# python error for downloading files from AWS

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python and the below code throws the error.Please help me to trouble shoot.This code is using for to download files from AMAZON WEB SERVICE (AWS).

```
import boto
import os

cwd = 'T:\\Amazon_receive\\AWS\\'
os.chdir(cwd)

S3_BUCKET = 'User_Name'
ACCESS_KEY = 'Password'
SECRET_KEY = 'aed1234xyz' 
conn = boto.connect_s3(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(S3_BUCKET, validate=False) 

def feeding_data(name, folder_path):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(cwd, name)):
        os.mkdir(name)
        os.chdir(name)
    else:
        os.chdir(name)
    files = os.listdir()

    for k in bucket.list(prefix=folder_path):
        fn = k.name.split('/')[-1]
        try:
            if fn not in files:
                k.get_contents_to_filename(fn)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

    os.chdir('..')

name = 'most_current_eb'
folder_path = '5776/frontend_5776/custom_output/most_current_eb/'
name = 'most_current_eb'
feeding_data(name, folder_path)
```

ERROR##

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\EA_Atribution.py", line 35, in <module>
    feeding_data(name, folder_path)
  File "C:\Python27\EA_Atribution.py", line 20, in feeding_data
    files = os.listdir()
TypeError: listdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
>>>
```

Thank you,
Mathew George

Answer (score 0):

As the error so clearly states:

```
TypeError: listdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

You should provide an argument (exactly 1) to [`listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), the... directory.

Comment: Can you please re write the code with correct argument . I am new to this python.

Comment: I don't know the directory you want to use... perhaps `folder_path` ? Or something else?

Comment: which folder path it reference to ,the one from amazon or the local path ?